# Convert string to float, C++ implementation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, floating-point

VS minimum double value = 2.2250738585072014e-308. atof function converts string to double value such as when you look at this value in the debugger you get original string representation.

```
double d = atof("2.2250738585072014e-308");    // debugger will show 2.2250738585072014e-308
```

As we can see, double value is not denormalized (there is no DEN)

I try to achieve the same precision when converting string to double. Here is the code:

```
double my_atof(char* digits, int digits_length, int ep)
{
int idot = digits_length;

for (int i = 0; i < digits_length; i++)
{
    if (digits[i] == '.')
    {
        idot = i;
        break;
    }
}

double accum = 0.0;
int power = ep + idot - 1;

for (int i = 0; i < digits_length; i++)
{
    if (digits[i] != '.')
    {
        if (digits[i] != '0')
        {
            double base_in_power = 1.0;

            if (power >= 0)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < power; k++) base_in_power *= 10.0;
            }
            else if (power < 0)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < -power; k++) base_in_power *= 0.1;
            }

            accum += (digits[i] - '0') * base_in_power;
        }
        power--;
    }
    else power = ep - 1;
}

return accum;
}
```

Now, let's try:

```
char* float_str = "2.2250738585072014";
int float_length = strlen(float_str);

double d = my_atof(float_str, float_length, -308);
```

Debugger shows that d = 2.2250738585072**379**e-308. I tried to substitute

```
for (int k = 0; k < -power; k++) base_in_power *= 0.1;
```

with

```
for (int k = 0; k < -power; k++) base_in_power /= 10.0;
```

but it results in denormalized value. How to achieve the same precision as VS does, such that debugger will show the same number?

Comment: The debugger is just showing a representation. Depending on the debugger you can change this. Perhaps if you are so concerned you can just look at the bit patterns

Comment: Why *= 0.1 and /= 10.0 gives different results while they should be identical?

Comment: @igntec Because they are not identical in finite precision binary arithmetic. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html et al.

Comment: Also good reading: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Also learn about errors and avoiding racking them up

Comment: You can't convert using IEEE arithmetic and expect a correct answer; you need higher precision arithmetic. See my article http://www.exploringbinary.com/decimal-to-floating-point-needs-arbitrary-precision/ .

Comment: @EdHeal “et al.” doesn't mean what you thinks it mean.

Comment: So what does it mean. I think it means and others

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with double representation of the `0.1` constant, or the division by `10.0`, which produces exactly the same result: negative powers of ten have no exact representation in floating-point numbers, because they have no exact representation as a sum of negative powers of 2.

When you compute negative powers of ten by repeated multiplication, you accumulate the error. First few negative powers come out right, but after about `0.000001` the difference becomes visible. Run this program to see what is happening:

```
double p10[] = {
    0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001, 0.000001, 0.0000001, 0.00000001, 0.000000001, 0.0000000001
};

int main(void) {
    double a = 1;
    for (int i = 0 ; i != 10 ; i++) {
        double aa = a * 0.1;
        double d = aa - p10[i];
        printf("%d %.30lf\n", aa == p10[i], d);
        a = aa;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
1 0.000000000000000000000000000000
1 0.000000000000000000000000000000
1 0.000000000000000000000000000000
1 0.000000000000000000000000000000
1 0.000000000000000000000000000000
0 0.000000000000000000000211758237
0 0.000000000000000000000026469780
0 0.000000000000000000000001654361
0 0.000000000000000000000000206795
0 0.000000000000000000000000025849
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/8CT75P)

The first few powers match exactly, but then some differences start appearing. When you use powers that you compute to compose the number during your string-to-float conversion, the accumulated errors make it into the final result. If the library function uses a look-up table (see [this implementation](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/academic/computer-science/history/pdp-11/rt/decus11/110800d1/atof.c) for an example), the result that you get would be different from result that they get.

You can fix your implementation by hard-coding a table of negative powers of ten, and referencing this table instead of computing the powers manually. Alternatively you could construct a *positive* power of ten by consecutive multiplications, and then do a single division `1 / pow10` to construct the corresponding negative power ([demo](https://ideone.com/b3Gn3I)).

Comment: Couldn't you also divide by increasing powers of 10 i.e. 10, 100, 1000 etc. to get accurate results?

Comment: @MarkRansom Right, that would also work, because multiplications to compute a positive power of ten would be exact, and then a single division would make the corresponding negative power without accumulating errors. I edited the answer and linked an additional demo. Thank you very much!